# Optimally searching for 2D points in the given area (webservice)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search, collections

I've got a kind of algorithmic & performance problem to solve with Java. I've got a large collection of 2D points (let's say there are about 100 000 of them). I want to get a set of them that are in the given area around the search point SP(X_sp, Y_sp), so that I'd like to get the points P(x y) that meets the criteria:

*x is between X_sp - constValue and X_sp + constValue AND y is between Y_sp - constValue and Y_sp + constValue*

To give you an idea of the number relations, constValue will be like 2, 5 or 10, and x, y will range between 0  and 1000. It's meant to be a webservice, so a possibility of searching around many different points at the same time must be taken into account.

As these are fixed points (not to change due to calculations or something), I thought that it would be optimal to provide one list of objects sorted by X and another one, but sorted by Y. Then, I'll first get the points within the X range, and, using references, get the set of this points from another list (sorted by Y). Then I'll narrow this selection by Y and in result get the points in the given area.

I don't know Java inside-out, so I'd like to consult with you the most optimized approach. Which objects should I use to store sorted points, which allow for fast search of objects within range? Or maybe I have to implement my custom algorithm for this task? Also, when it comes to storing the points in the database, are SQL queries sufficiently fast to deliver the results? Or maybe NoSQL dbs are better for this?

I'm going to perform my own tests, but I'm looking for a starting candidates.

Comment: This is far too broad.

Comment: Unless you have a specific question about an attempted solution to this problem, this question is not suitable for SO. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: All you have there is a problem statement. First find an optimized algorithm to achieve the task and then if you need help optimizing your code, reach out here.

Comment: SO is not the right place for these questions. However, you should take a look at [Spatial Databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a `TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>`, where the key to the map is the `x` coordinate and for each `x` coordinate, you have a list of `y` coordinates. You can then use [`floorEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry-K-) and [`ceilingEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry-K-) to find the `x` coordinates that fall within your range. Then for each `TreeSet<Integer>` set that you get, you can use [`ceiling`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#ceiling-E-) and [`floor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor-E-) to get the appropriate entries.

Of course, this only gives you the coordinates of the bounds of your box (the four corners). But `TreeSet` also has a [`subset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet-E-E-) that will give you a range of values. You will have to use this twice; once for the list of `x` coordinates (you can get the key set using the `keySet` method of the map) that are within your bounds, then for each `x` coordinate, the `y` coordinates that are within the bounds. So the pseudocode would be sort of like this:

```
List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();
int lowerX = points.ceilingKey(x - c);
int upperX = points.floorKey(x + c);
for each x coordinate in points.entrySet().subset(lowerX, upperX)
    TreeSet<Integer> yCoordinates = points.get(x);
    lowerY = yCoordinates.ceiling(y - c);
    upperY = yCoordinates.ceiling(y + c);

    for each y coordinate in yCoordinates.subset(lowerY, upperY)
       result.add(new Point(x, y))
```

I haven't tested this out, so there are probably some bugs or something I've missed. Let me know and I'll correct the answer.

The `floor` and `ceiling` calls are `log(n)` I believe -- this is where you get the performance benefit because if you use a list, it would be `O(n)` to look that up.

**Note:** I don't know if this is the most performant. SO is typically not the place for such an open-ended question so you might have more luck elsewhere.